# Spring integration + oracle store procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, spring-integration

I´m trying to replicate the spring-integration store procedure coffee example from PostgreSQL to Oracle. Without success.
Here is the link to the original code 
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/stored-procedures-postgresql

I decided to start with just the procedure to get all the coffees, so I remove all the references to the getCoffee by name in the project.

Here is the code to my store procedure:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE find_all_coffee_beverages AS
begin
    for x in (SELECT id, coffee_name, 
                coffee_description
                FROM coffee_beverages
               ORDER BY ID) loop
        dbms_output.put_line
            (x.coffee_description);
    end loop;
end;
```

Here is my spring context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
        <property name="user" value="admin" />
        <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
            <props merge="default">
                <prop key="MinLimit">3</prop>
                <prop key="MaxLimit">20</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="findAllProcedureRequestChannel" />

    <int:gateway id="gateway" default-request-timeout="4000"
        default-reply-timeout="4000"
        service-interface="org.springframework.integration.service.CoffeeService">
        <int:method name="findAllCoffeeBeverages" request-channel="findAllProcedureRequestChannel" />
    </int:gateway>

    <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
        id="outbound-gateway-storedproc-find-all" data-source="dataSource"
        ignore-column-meta-data="true" request-channel="findAllProcedureRequestChannel"
        expect-single-result="true" stored-procedure-name="FIND_ALL_COFFEE_BEVERAGES">
        <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="ref"
            row-mapper="org.springframework.integration.support.CoffeBeverageMapper" />
    </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="5000">
        <int:transactional />
    </int:poller>

</beans>
```

So I compile it and run it with maven like this: mvn clean package exec:java -e
It compiles perfectly but when it try to run I get the next exceptions:

```
 --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) @ oracle-stored-procedures ---
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call FIND_ALL_COFFEE_BEVERAGES(?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FIND_ALL_COFFEE_BEVERAGES'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:233)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:388)14:01:56.804 WARN  [org.springframework.integration.Main.main()][org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway] failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcOutboundGateway#0]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:239)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:203)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:306)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:269)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:260)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy16.findAllCoffeeBeverages(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.Main.main(Main.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:291)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Does anyone knows why am I getting that exceptions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bad SQL grammar [{call FIND_ALL_COFFEE_BEVERAGES(?)}]` It looks to me like Spring is trying to call the procedure with a parameter, but since your procedure does not actually take any arguments, I'm not sure why it's doing that.

Comment: does anyone has an spring-integration example where it calls an store procedure?

Answer (score 1):

For a solution please see the Spring Integration Forum posting at:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135237-Spring-integration-oracle-store-procedures